# Reconnect to linux service output after exiting with Ctrl+C

Tags: linux, service, console, rabbitmq, stdout

**Configuration**

I have installed *RabbitMQ* and *Celery* in a *Docker* container to try asynchronous tasks with *Python*.
I connect to the running container with multiple consoles to start the services and monitor everything. Everything runs fine. I can start some tasks and monitor the results.

**Problem**

When I start rabbitmq-server I get the *output to the console* that started the server (service?).

If I exit the "output" with Ctrl+C , the server keeps running as a service. (I checked "ps -ef" and also run some tasks)

> How is it possible to direct the "output" to the console again?

Currently, I just kill the process and rerun rabitmq-server.

**My Conclusion & Questions**

I think that it is possible to get the output from a file that RabbitMQ is also logging to.

But this is not the point!

I am not sure, but I think that currently ( when I start the server ) the output is directed to the stdout and somehow stdout is my console. But if I exit that "connection - attachment" my console stops getting the stdout from this service. But where does the stdout go? Is it lost? Can it cause any error? Or maybe fill up disk space with logging? Why some services start without output and others start with? Can I connect to any services output?

**Forgiveness**

This is my first question and I am really sorry if it is not properly structured or explained well.

***Thank you***

Answer (score 0):

Any service running in docker when writing logs to console , the logs are redirected to the stdout of docker and can be retrieved by running the command

```
docker container logs CONTAINER_ID|CONTAINER_NAME
```

More can be read here https://takacsmark.com/docker-logs/

Comment: this should not be the case because it should not be a Docker issue. I am just using Docker and I connect to the running container with docker exec -it bash. So I just have a console in the container. I am considering that as a clean environment that everything runs inside. Maybe I should not refer to Docker at all.

Comment: Or perhaps you may want to configure RabbitMq to log to a specific path and mount that path from the host.